# How to get Vuforia and MRTK MultiScene System works?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

I'm working on AR Project with the HoloLens 2. I need to recognize a QRcode to build my Buttons in the real world at the right positions. So what I'm doing I used MRTK 2.2 and I applied the MRTK configuration. I work with the Multi Scene System so that I have MainScene Manager where all children are not destroyable.

The camera is under the MainSceneManger and I attached to it Vuforia Behavior and DefaultIntialization error Handler and the Image target is under other Scene. The camera could not detect the Image which is in the Fact my QRcode, but when I put the ImageTarget under the MainSceneManager where the Main camera is it works fine. How could I get this work when the Image Target and Main camera are not under the Same Scene.

Ps: In the attached picture I Loaded the Haupseite Scene intentionally so that you can see where the ImageTarget placed.
[image]

Comment: typically you don't really need vuforia for qr code and can just use existing c# qr code libraries

Comment: I Know that HoloLens 2 can read QRcode from Script but i need to use Vuforia for other reasons . So i found a Solution , for those who have the same issue you must  uncheck the Vuforia Engine  from Script and check it again in the convient Scene where you need to use Vuforia

Comment: How did you make it work ?